# google chrome view and store server certificate before clicking to proceed anyway

Tags: google-chrome

When I visit intranet site at work in google chrome I am shown page where it informs me to either proceed anyway or safety.  It is standard google chrome page for any self signed certificate.  I want to view and store this certificate so then I can use it with other utilities / programs.

Please guide.

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the certificate on your system. [Windows] Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates

Comment: problem is how to identify what certificate from the repository ?